# Constant Values on Arrangements of Points under Maps $S^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, linear-transformations, group-actions

The following result would be a generalisation of [this result of Floyd](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1955-006-06/S0002-9939-1955-0073978-9/S0002-9939-1955-0073978-9.pdf), as well as The Borsuk-Ulam Theorem. Let $X\subseteq S^n$. Call $[X]$ the arrangement given by $X$, defined as the equivalence class of all sets $Y\subseteq S^n$ such that there is a rotation $\rho$ of $S^n$ such that $\rho(X)=Y$. Is it the case that for every continuous $f:S^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, and every $(n-m+2)$-subset $X$ of $S^n$ there exists $Y\in[X]$ and a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that for all $s\in Y$, $f(s)=c$? This is at least true for $m=1$ and $n=1,2$.

Comment: Very interesting question. Borsuk Ulam makes this seem likely for the case $n=m$ as well. I feel like there should be a fairly straightforward argument for that: something like draw a path in $\mathbb R^n$ connecting the image of the two antipodal points to the boundary of $f(S^n)$. By continuity, the diameter of the preimages of points on this path should take on any value between $0$ and the maximum, and that is equivalent to your conjecture in this special case.

Comment: Unfortunately, multiplicity of points mapping to a point complicates this so that you can't in general select continuous functions of points in the preimage connecting choices from the preimages at the start and end of the curve.

Comment: Yes, it was really more of a plausibility argument than a rigorous one.